# Tower not updating newly created files

Tags: git, git-tower

I am using [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) to work with a Git repository. My problem is that when I add new files locally they are not showing up in Tower. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Simply interacting with the Tower window is enough to get it to refresh the state for me. Could you add more detail? I created a new file and added it from the command line, and Tower reflected the changes as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more specific I can be. I created some files within sub-directories of my local repository. These files are not reflected in Tower. I have tried refreshing with no luck.

Comment: Yes, they were hidden in my .gitignore. Good call, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They are likely hidden by a rule in a .gitignore file. Do you see them when you do git status from the command line? If not, check .gitignore.